# Extending the Drawable Class (using ProxyDrawable example)

Tags: android, android-drawable

**Overview:** I'm trying to make a class which extends Drawable. My test app does not behave as I expect. No image fills the screen, when I expect one should.

**Details:** I am trying to understand how to create custom Drawables that take other Drawables as parameters and manipulate them as desired. I've read through and generally understand the source code for obvious existing examples such as LayerDrawable and LevelListDrawable, then I came across a very stripped back version of this concept in the [ProxyDrawable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.6_r1/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ProxyDrawable.java#ProxyDrawable) class.

As I understand it, it basically;

- overrides Drawable's getters to take the properties of the Drawable passed to its constructor as its own.
- overrides Drawable's setters to pass on properties down to the passed in Drawable.
- calls the passed in Drawable's own draw() method to draw it to the ProxyDrawable's canvas.

I have tried to implement this in a simple test app, as shown in the code below.

The FrameLayout frame1 is set to match_parent for both the width and height in my activity_main.xml so it takes up the full screen.

When I run this test app however, the ic_launcher image does not appear in the frame.

As noted in the code comments, if I use the ic_launcher directly when setting the frame's background, the image does appear. Hence the problem must be in the MyProxyDrawable class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyProxyDrawable myDrawable = new MyProxyDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        FrameLayout myFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame1);

        myFrame.setBackground(myDrawable);

            // ** NOTE **
            // The ic_launcher image fills the whole screen if
            // I replace the line above with the line below, so there
            // is no problem with the resource or frame.

            //myFrame.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    }

    public class MyProxyDrawable extends Drawable {

        private Drawable mProxy;
        private boolean mMutated;

        public MyProxyDrawable(Drawable target) {
            mProxy = target;
        }

        public Drawable getProxy() {
            return mProxy;
        }

        public void setProxy(Drawable proxy) {
            if (proxy != this) {
                mProxy = proxy;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (mProxy != null) {
                mProxy.draw(canvas);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
            return mProxy != null ? mProxy.getIntrinsicWidth() : -1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
            return mProxy != null ? mProxy.getIntrinsicHeight() : -1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return mProxy != null ? mProxy.getOpacity() : PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
        }

        @Override
        public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
            if (mProxy != null) {
                mProxy.setFilterBitmap(filter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setDither(boolean dither) {
            if (mProxy != null) {
                mProxy.setDither(dither);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
            if (mProxy != null) {
                mProxy.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
            if (mProxy != null) {
                mProxy.setAlpha(alpha);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable mutate() {
            if (mProxy != null && !mMutated && super.mutate() == this) {
                mProxy.mutate();
                mMutated = true;
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try to override onBoundsChange

Comment: @pskink I overrode onBoundsChange adding `mProxy.setBounds(bounds);` and it worked. Thank you!
I've been pondering why this was necessary over the last hour since getting your post, but the lightbulb just isn't going on. Why isn't it enough to call the passed in object's draw() method in my new class' draw() method?
I'd really like to understand as I know failing to do so will only lead to bad code on my part.

Comment: i think you should keep the symetry and call mProxy.onBoundsChange, the reason why it works now is that Drawable by default has empty size/bounds, try to NOT override onBoundsChange and try to debug mProxy.draw, and you will see how empty mPeoxy draws itself

Comment: @pskink. I get it now. When my new class object is created its bounds are empty. When it's first draw, its bounds are changed to fill the screen, which calls onBoundsChange() so I can pass that on to mProxy. Brilliant. Thank you.